# typeahead loading but not visible

Tags: jquery, typeahead.js

I am new to typeahead.js and was trying to implement a simple example.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
    <head>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='../libraries/jquery/jquery-2.1.0.js'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='../libraries/typeahead/typeahead.bundle.js'></script>

        <title> CIQ-Flow </title>

    </head>

<body>
<input type='text' id="search"/>
<p> some text </p>
    <script>
$('#search').css("background-color",'blue');

$('#search').typeahead([
{
name: 'planets',
local: [ "Mercury", "Venus", "Earth", "Mars", "Jupiter", "Saturn", "Uranus", "Neptune" ]
}
]);
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

The above example just tries to show the values in the text box. This should be a straight forward example and should have worked. Do not know where it is going wrong. Some hint or suggestion will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using a suggestion engine (e.g. bloodhound) with typeahead.js.

Here is a jsFiddle showing you how you can implement a solution

http://jsfiddle.net/Fresh/hk4ej/

It's based on the "Dead Simple" example found [here](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/).

The code is as follows:

```
// instantiate the bloodhound suggestion engine
var planets = new Bloodhound({
datumTokenizer: function (d) {
    return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.planet);
},
queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    local: [{
        planet: "Mercury"
    }, {
        planet: "Venus"
    }, {
        planet: "Earth"
    }, {
        planet: "Mars"
    }, {
        planet: "Jupiter"
    }, {
        planet: "Saturn"
    }, {
        planet: "Uranus"
    }, {
        planet: "Neptune"
    }]
});

// initialize the bloodhound suggestion engine
planets.initialize();

// instantiate the typeahead UI
$('#typeahead').typeahead(null, {
    displayKey: 'planet',
    source: planets.ttAdapter()
});
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply. But does it need to be executed on the server side? Becuase, when I copy your code in a html file and execute, I am not getting any reaction from the text box! I am not getting any error from the console either.

Comment: If you copy the above code into a HTML file you also need to make sure that you include <script> references to the jQuery and typeahead.js javascript files in your <head> section.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did a silly mistake. My text box had different ID, which you changed in your reply. Thanks for the help

Comment: Sorry for changing the id! Glad I could help @Adithya